Approximate Solutions and Solver Settings in CPLEX and Gurobi
CPLEX offers functionalities to approximate solutions for nonconvex optimization problems rather than guaranteeing global optimality. It includes an option to find solutions satisfying first-order optimality conditions, which can be specified in YALMIP using $$\texttt{sdpsettings(`solver',`cplex',`cplex.optimalitytarget',2)}.$$
Does Gurobi provide any similar settings?

The CPLEX setting of optimalitytarget to 2 is to seek a locally optimal solution of a non-convex QP.  Gurobi only seeks a global optimum (whether the problem is convex or non-convex), and has no provision to seek a local optimum which is not a global optimum; However, the relative and absolute gap tolerance can be set in Gurobi to determine when to terminate.
